# SQL Server - copy row where new foreign key is present

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where a user can add a new [Application]. This [Application] can contain MANY [Variations]. a [Variation] can have MANY [VariationLines]

for example here is some data to clarify:

```
Project             
ProjectID   Name            
    1       Test Project            

Application             
ApplicationID   ProjectID   ApplicationValue        
      1             1             £500      

Variation               
VariationID ApplicationID   VariationTotalAmount        
     1             1               £100     
     2             1               £250     

VariationLine               
VariationLineID VariationID PreviousPercentage  VariationValue   VariationPercentage    ApplicationID
        1            1             0%              £50.00                50%                   1     
        2            2             0%              £62.50                25%                   1
```

**The Question**

When a user adds an Application [ApplicationID:2], I want SQL Server to COPY the ROWS associated with [ApplicationID:1]..

So with the example data above, how could I copy [VariationLineID:1] AND [VariationLineID:2], and  specify that if the exist on the new Application [Application:2] that it doesn't need to  COPY them again?

This query selects the rows to copy but I dont understand how to stop them COPYING again so could someone please point me in the right direction to prevent this?

```
    INSERT INTO VariationLine 
            (variationid, 
             applicationid, 
             applicationcounter, 
             variationpercentage, 
             variationvalue, 
             previouspercentage, 
             projectid, 
             totalvariationvalue, 
             variationretention) 
SELECT VariationLine.variationid, 
       ApplicationID = (2), 
       ApplicationCounter = (2), 
       VariationPercentage = variationpercentage, 
       VariationValue = 0, 
       PreviousPercentage = variationpercentage, 
       ProjectReference = projectreference, 
       TotalVariationValue = totalvariationvalue, 
       VariationRetention = 0 
FROM   variationsincluded 
WHERE  projectid = (1) 
       AND applicationcounter = (2) - 1 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   applications 
                   WHERE  VariationLine.applicationid != 
                          applications.applicationid)
```

The above CODE will select the correct results, after running once VariationLineID:3 and VariationLineID:4 are INSERTED.. now if I was to run this again then it would insert the same data again, I only want this to be INSERTED ONCE

below are the **Desired Results** after the Query above has been ran:

```
Application
ApplicationID      ProjectID     ApplicationValue
      2                1               £500

VariationLine               
VariationLineID VariationID PreviousPercentage  VariationValue  VariationPercentage
        1             1             0%               £50.00              50%
        2             2             0%               £62.50              25%
        3             1             50%              £0.00               50%
        4             2             25%              £0.00               25%
```

so to explain, the Query would copy VariationLineID 1 and 2, and re-insert them into the same table based on the FOREIGN KEY relationship of ApplicationID. The PreviousPrecentage and VariationPercentage for VariationLineID 3 would be taken from VariationLineID 1, and so on... this enables the user to amend to 2nd Application's VariationLine and not affect Application 1

Comment: Is there a typo in the first line of The Question?   When a user adds Application 2, you want to copy the lines associated with Application 2?   How can there be any lines if it was just added?

Comment: yes sorry, ill amend now

Comment: This question would benefit from an example of "desired results".   You seem to be saying at the same time that you want to copy the lines associated with AppID 1, and yet NOT copy them "again".   What does that mean?

Comment: It sounds a lot like you want to use the application id 1 as a template for new applications. If so then you could define triggers for insert on application and variation that inserts copies of the rows for appid 1, but with the new appid.

Comment: I would like to use Application 1 as a template for Application 2, Then If i was to create Application 3, Application 2 would be the template

Comment: You don't want any new rows inserted into `variation` when you add a new `application` ?

Comment: No, this is being used as a place where the user can add comments, and a full variation price, The VariationLine is a way of the cost being broken down and paid at stages of completion :)